# Layout for key-value pairs with custom titles from Cursor with single row

Tags: android

I need to show data from single row like listview, but each list item is column from cursor. Row has 7 columns. Like this

```
Address: row["addres"]
--------------------------
Zipcode: row["zip-code"]
--------------------------
Name: row["name"]
--------------------------
......
```

1. One way is to use ***LinearLayout*** with 7 nested horizontal ***LinearLayouts***. Titles hardcoded in layout's xml file.
2. Second - is to use ***RelativeLayout*** to achieve same result.
3. And third - is to use ListView and populate data from single row through adapter.

First 2 is simpliest and obvious ways, but how to do they looks like listview?

Last is more complex, and i have no idea, how to populate each column to it's own ListView item.

Comment: Check https://www.google.co.in/#q=cursoradapter+example

Comment: ofc i'm using cursoradapter, but for the other things, like i have alot of rows, and I need to create listview item for each row. BUt I need listview item for each column. NOT row.